# React navigation V6 typescript how to pass theme prop to navigation container

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a react native, typescript, app. I am using React Navigation V6 and React Native Paper for my UI. I am also using Redux toolkit for my state management. All of the parts are working just fine.
I followed the React Native Paper [Guide on theming with React Navigation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/theming-with-react-navigation).
All of this is working perfectly too, when I keep the Navigation container in App.tsx.
Soon as I moved the Navigation container into a separate component and I try to pass the theme prop to it, I keep getting multiple errors, like the ones shown below.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'background' of undefined

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

**App.tsx**

```
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import * as React from "react";
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  MD3DarkTheme,
  MD3LightTheme,
  PaperProvider,
  adaptNavigationTheme,
 } from "react-native-paper";
 import merge from "deepmerge";
 import { Provider } from "react-redux";
 import PublicStack from "./src/navigation/PublicStack";
 import { PreferencesContext } from "./src/context/PreferencesContext";
 import { appStore } from "./src/store/appStore";
 import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
 import { IAuthState } from "./src/interfaces/IAuthentication";

 // Redux state store load from local storage if present
 // Code removed

 const { LightTheme, DarkTheme } = adaptNavigationTheme({
   reactNavigationLight: NavigationDefaultTheme,
   reactNavigationDark: NavigationDarkTheme,
 });

 const CombinedDefaultTheme = merge(MD3LightTheme, LightTheme);
 const CombinedDarkTheme = merge(MD3DarkTheme, DarkTheme);

 export default function App() {
   const [isThemeDark, setIsThemeDark] = React.useState(true);
   let appTheme = isThemeDark ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme;

   const toggleTheme = React.useCallback(() => {
     return setIsThemeDark(!isThemeDark);
   }, [isThemeDark]);

    const preferences = React.useMemo(
      () => ({
        toggleTheme,
        isThemeDark,
      }),
      [toggleTheme, isThemeDark]
     );

     return (
       <Provider store={appStore}>
         <PreferencesContext.Provider value={preferences}>
           <PaperProvider theme={appTheme}>

             // This block with NavigationContainer has been moved into another 
             // component: AppNavigator
             // <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme}>
             //   <PublicStack />
             // </NavigationContainer>

          </PaperProvider>
         </PreferencesContext.Provider>
       </Provider>
      );
     }
```

**AppNavigator.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer, Theme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import HomeStack from "./HomeStack";
import PublicStack from "./PublicStack";
import { useAppSelector } from "../store/hook";
import { selectAuthState } from "../store/authSlice";

const AppNavigator = (theme: Theme) => {
  const authState = useAppSelector(selectAuthState);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      {/* Conditional stack navigator rendering based on login state */}
      {authState?.isLoggedIn ? <HomeStack /> : <PublicStack />}
     </NavigationContainer>
    );
  };

  export default AppNavigator;
```

How can I properly pass my theme into AppNavigator.tsx?